# Reading into array

Tags: c, arrays

Please help, I need to read an input txt file into an array and print it out put somehow I keep getting error message.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reading_into_array(int A[]);

#define MAXVALS 100
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int numbers[100], i;
    reading_into_array(numbers[MAXVALS]);
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        printf("%d", numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

/*input information*/

void
reading_into_array(int A[]){
    double inp;
    int n = 0;
    while(scanf("%lf",&inp) == 1){
        A[n++] = inp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help you with your problem we need to know: 1) The expected behavior of your code and 2) What actually happens, including your error messages. Otherwise we can only guess ;) Please take a look at the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 3):

- `numbers[MAXVALS]` is out-of-range and its type doesn't match with the function argument. use `numbers` instead.
- Avoid using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration, which invokes *undefined behavior*. Initialize `numbers` like `int numbers[100]={0},i;`

Comment: Hey thanks for answering my question, just a thing about your second point. Cause my input contain non-integer numbers as well so do you know how can I printf the double value for my array?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that `inp` is `double`. Use `double` as array elements and use correct format specifier to print the `doubl`e values.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function that takes an array as a parameter, you only need to supply the name of the array, e.g. numbers. "numbers[MAXVALS]" would supply the value of the MAXVALth element of this array. This is wrong for two reasons:

1. the function needs an array, not an element
2. The array has a size MAXVAL; its elements are counted from zero to MAXVAL-1, so the MAXVALth element does not even exist

If you want floating point numbers in your array, declare the array as double A[MAXVAL] everywhere.

Last note: the reading_into_array function should have a check that it will prevent it from putting more than MAXVAL numbers into the array, or you risk that it will corrupt memory and crash your program.